# In informal speech, can you leave замуж out from "выйти замуж"?

Tags: грамматика, выражения

Is it appropriate to leave out замуж like this?

Она чего вышла за этого мужчину?

Comment: yep, totally, like in "Выйдешь за меня?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's OK because it's clear what is meant. Выйти за кого-то = to get married.

Comment: also to go an work for someone—fill in for them ;)

Comment: @VCH250 good point!

Comment: ))))) That evokes a number of jokes: "Выйди за меня... в понедельник на работу", почему фразу "Выйди за меня" я слышу только на работе, and so on.

Comment: @Elena ))))))))